# updating spinner based on another spinner's selected item

Tags: android, spinner

What is wrong with this code?

I'm having two spinners. One for 'category' and the second for 'subcategory'. When an item is chosen in the category spinner I want to re-load the relevant sub-categories accordingly.

```
        mSpnrCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // SubCategories
                String[] aSubCategory = new String[SUBCATS.length];

... Some code for preparing aSubCategory.

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterSubCategories = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewRequestActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aSubCategory);
                dataAdapterSubCategories.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpnrSubCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapterSubCategories);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

when the activity is loaded this code is called and it works fine loading the subcategories of the first category. However, when I change category manually this code is called but results with empty spinner for subcategories. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your subcategory adapter (`mSpnrSubCategory`) as a global variable.
Then whenever category spinner click, change the data of subcategory then `notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> mSpnrSubCategory;
    ArrayList<String> aSubCategory;
    mSpnrCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // SubCategories
               ...
               mSpnrSubCategory.notifyDataSetChanged();    
         }
    });
```

I suggest to use `ArrayList<String> instead of String[]`
Hope this help

Comment: Actually to use the ArrayList advice did the trick. the problem a stupid mistake with loading the array. Thank you.